# including XML in page that causes PHP to crash

Tags: php, xml, include

This might have been answered somewhere else if so sorry. I have an dynamic XML document on a remote server that has the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` on the first line. This causes PHP to throw an exemption I'm guessing because of the ?>

My question is how do I include this document in my page without causing PHP to throw an exception?

Cheers

EDIT: I'm including by using `require`, probably not the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with the `short_open_tag` configuration option, which will interpret `<?` as a PHP opening tag. You may want to try using the [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function to set `short_open_tag` to `false` immediately before including the remote file, and then switch it back afterwards.

EDIT: If the file/URL you're referencing doesn't contain any PHP code that needs to be run, you can use the [readfile()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function to read and output its contents in one fell swoop. This will break if the file, as downloaded from the server, contains PHP snippets, but should work if the data is completely ready to go.

Comment: Tried your solution and no dice :( After I thought about it I realise I might be using the wrong way to include it in the page. Question updated.

Comment: Require shouldn't make a difference Rudiger.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I updated my answer with a note about readfile(), which might yield better results for your use case.

Comment: @Justin Spahr-Summers: " This will break if the file, as downloaded from the server, contains PHP snippets" - that is incorrect: readfile() doesn't parse the downloaded file, therefore it won't break if the file contains PHP snippets - as it's never executed, just sent to the client the way it was received from remote server.

Comment: @Piskvor Sorry, the way I phrased that was unclear. I meant exactly that – if the file contains PHP snippets *which are supposed to be executed*, they won't be, and this will break the application in question.

Comment: Sigh, although that works in a way that first line is screwing up the output, I made a local copy of the file and although now PHP doesn't throw an error and displays it properly, that line in the question kills the rendering of the page, if I take that line out of the local copy it works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to make a separate question for this, but quick answer: if you're performing XHTML output of your own before the opening `<?xml` tag, and you only wish to include the *contents* of the other document, you will have to perform some more complex file manipulation using tools like `fopen()`, `fread()`, etc., to skip over that tag.

Comment: Cheers for that, got there in the end with your last comment :)

Answer (score 4):

`require` and `include` are the wrong tools for this. Both include the page, yes - but then they attempt to run it as PHP code *on your machine*, without any security measures. Imagine what would happen if the remote machine returned `<?php system('poweroff') ?>` - PHP on your machine would happily try to shutdown your server.

The function you're looking for is [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) - it fetches the remote file and outputs it - without trying to run it as PHP.